# How can we define that function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I want to show that $M=\{\tau \in S_4\mid \tau (4)=4\}$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.

To do that we have to consider a function $f(x)$ that gives the isomorphism of $M$ with $S_3$, i.e., we have to describe what $f(x)$ is in $S_3$ for each $x\in M$, right?

We have that $f(\tau)\in \{1,2,3\}$ for $\tau \in S_3$ and $f(\tau (4))=4$, right?

How can we define that function?

Answer (score 2):

An element of $S_3$ is a map from $\{1,2,3\}$ to itself. If we are given $\tau\in M$ then a priori this is a map from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to itself. Of course we can always restrict such a map to a subset, thus obtaining a mpa $\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$. But by the given condition that $\tau(4)=4$ (and hence $\tau(x)\ne 4$ for $x\ne 4$) we see that we can consider this restriction as a map $\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3\}$ (and a bijective map of course) as desired.

Comment: So, do we consider a function $$f:S_3\rightarrow M $$ and due to the restriction we consider the function $$f:S_3\rightarrow S_3$$ ? Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: And why is this map bijective? To show that, do we not have to have a specific definition of the function?

Comment: @MaryStar The map $\tau|_{\{1,2,3\}}\colon\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3\}$ is bijective because it is injective (and it is injective because $\tau$ is. The map $M\to S_3$, $\tau\mapsto \tau|_{\{1,2,3\}}$ is bijective because we have a quite obious inverse map $S_3\to S_4$, $\sigma \mapsto \tilde\sigma$ where $\tilde\sigma(k)=\begin{cases}\sigma(k),&kne 4\\4,&k=4\end{cases}$.

Comment: Is $\tilde{\sigma}$ the function $f$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar $\sigma\mapsto\tilde\sigma$ is a function $S_3\to M$ that is in fact an isomorphism. $\tilde\sigma$ itself is just an element of $S_4$ (obtained from $\sigma\in S_3$) and as such happens to be a map as well (namely a permutation), but is not of significance here. I am afraid you are confused because we are looking for a map from one set of maps to another set of maps that is compatible with composition, i.e., with a map from the set of pairs of maps to the set of  maps ...

Comment: We have the function $f:S_3\rightarrow M$ with $f(\sigma )=\tilde{\sigma}$, where $$\tilde{\sigma}(1)=\sigma (1) \\ \tilde{\sigma}(2)=\sigma (2) \\ \tilde{\sigma}(3)=\sigma (3) \\ \tilde{\sigma}(4)=4$$ right? I haven't really understood how can we show that this function is bijective. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Specifically I am stuck at how to show that this function is surjective because of $\tilde{\sigma}(4)=4$, this hasn't an original at $S_3$...

Answer (score 2):

Given $\sigma\in\ S_3$ define $f(\sigma)$ to be the permutation in $S_4$ fixing $4$ and agreeing with $\sigma$ on $1$, $2$ and $3$.

Comment: To show that this function is bijective, do we not have to have a specific definition of the function?

Comment: But what Foobaz gave here *is* a specific definition of the function $f$, isn't it?

Comment: So, is the definition of $f$ the following? $$f:S_3\mapsto M \\ f (\sigma(k))=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\sigma (k) & , k\neq 4\\ 
4 & , k=4
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Comment: That is the definition of $f$.

Comment: I got stuck because when $\sigma (k)\in S_3$ how can $k$ get the value $4$ ?

Comment: We have the function $f:S_3\rightarrow M$ with $f(\sigma )=\tilde{\sigma}$, where $$\tilde{\sigma}(1)=\sigma (1) \\ \tilde{\sigma}(2)=\sigma (2) \\ \tilde{\sigma}(3)=\sigma (3) \\ \tilde{\sigma}(4)=4$$ right? How can we show that this function is bijective?

Comment: Specifically I am stuck at how to show that this function is surjective because of $\tilde{\sigma}(4)=4$, this hasn't an original at $S_3$...

Comment: Note that $f$ is a function between two finite sets of the same cardinality (size) (namely $6$) and hence it suffices to show that the function is injective to show that it is bijective. Any injective map between two finite sets is automatically surjective.

Comment: If you want to show surjectivity explicitly let $\sigma\in M$ and note that $f(\sigma\restriction_A)=\sigma$ where $A=\{1,2,3\}$